# Div goes under first div when page is resized

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have something like this:

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <img src="leftphoto.jpg" id="left">
    <div id="right">Description</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color:#252525;
}
#container{
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  height: 40vw;
}
#left{
  max-width: 75vw;
  height:100%;
}
#right{
  min-width: 300px;
  height:100%;
  color:white;
  width:20vw;
  background-color: red;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 11px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

I want the right div to go down, under left div with the same width. How can I achieve that?

What I have:

[image]

When I resize window, it is smaller:

[image]

But I want the right div to go down, under the left div and also I would like to get the same width on both divs:

[image]

I was trying a lot of different things, but I couldn't achieve this. Do you have any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use flex blox to achieve this. Simply place on the container of the divs. Once that is done you can change the divs placement by `flex-direction` row/column. Similarly, for  placing the 2nd div above the first div once the size reduce, you can set media query for a specific screen where you can reverse the column and you done.

```css
.container{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}



@media screen and (max-width:768px){
  .container{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column-reverse
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885__340.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <p>Content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! flex-direction is what I was looking for.

Comment: happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Create a second container in your html and they will naturally align under eachother

```
<div class="container">
      <div class="content-Container">
        <img src="leftphoto.jpg" id="left" />
        <div id="right">Description</div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

and then position them to the middle of the page by adding style to the parent container